# Javafx How to make TableColumn cells selectable but not editable using Javafx

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to create table using Javafx, i need for some columns cells to be selectable but not editable,

if i used :  `textColumn.setEditable(true);`
but it will make it editable

if i used : `textColumn.setEditable(false);` it will be neither selectable nor editabe

how can i make column selectable but not editable ?

Here it is my code sample

```
    TableColumn<Tuple, String> textColumn= new TableColumn<>();
    textColumn.setText(column.getName());
    textColumn.setMinWidth(column.getWidth());
    textColumn.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: Have you enabled cell selection? Also what do you mean by "selectable column"? Should you be able to select the whole column as a single "entity" or just select the cells in this column?

Comment: @fabian, if you are talking about 'table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);' then yes i did

Comment: @fabian, i want to be able to copy the contents of cells not whole columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default copying mechanism for `TableView` (columns could contain arbitraty value types that could require costom treatment when copying to the clipboard). You should implement the copying mechanism yourself, if needed.

Example:

```
tableView.setOnKeyReleased(evt -> {
    if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getCode() == KeyCode.C) {
        List<TablePosition> selectedCells = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
        if (!selectedCells.isEmpty()) {
            TablePosition selectedCell = selectedCells.get(0);
            if (selectedCell.getTableColumn() == textColumn) {
                String value = textColumn.getCellData(selectedCell.getRow());
                Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(value);
                clipboard.setContent(content);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This needs to be done in addition to doing

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

It assumes you're using to the standard cell type.